# Excel: In which xml-file are the data stored in a xlsx-zip-file

Tags: excel, xml, zip, xlsx

I have some troubles with an Excel-file when opening it:

```
Entfernter Teil: Teil /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml. (Zeichnungsform)
Entferntes Feature: Objekt von /xl/printerSettings/printerSettings1.bin-Part (Datenspeicher)
```

When I click yes to see the file I'm missing all the data I entered with a check box and Exel opens the file with a repair-modus. An older version of the Excel has the data.

I'm wonder where I can find the data if I open the xlsx-container with zip. I suppose it should be an xml-file but couldn't find it. I have only one sheet.

[image]

**Update (1)**
I found where the data are: *sharedStrings.xml*.

[image]

But the results from check boxes are not in this xml-File. The check box info are in directory ctrlProps (for example *ctrlProp1.xml*) but there are no links between content of *ctrlProp1.xml* and *sharedStrings.xml*.

***ctrlProp1.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<formControlPr xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" objectType="CheckBox" lockText="1" noThreeD="1"/>
```

Comment: might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401733/how-do-i-unzip-an-xlsx-file or http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks for the link, very interesting. The data seems under xl/tables. But the problem is that in my case there is no directory tables.